# R-exams: How to change labels for multiple choice alternatives to distinguish from cloze items (a, b, ...)

Tags: r-exams

I am trying to create pdf exam sets using exams2pdf(...) using templates "exam.tex", "solution.tex". I want to have some questions of type "cloze", with e.g. both single choice questions and numeric questions. The problem is that the cloze question is itemized with (a), (b), ... The same labels (a), (b), ... are also used for the different possible answers to single choice questions. So, using the template questions "lm.Rmd" and "switzerland.Rmd" I get this in the question sheet:

[image: From question sheet]

While the front page answer sheet looks like this.

[image: Front page answer sheet]

This obviously doesn't look great. I have tried to modify the "exam.tex" template by changing the "answerlist" environment definition, specifically changing

```
 ...\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}...
```

to e.g.

```
...\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}...
```

However, this appeared to have no effect on the output. I moreover tried to modify the \exmchoice definition, changing "(a)" to e.g. "(A)". This only affected the labels on the front page, not in the question sheet. The exams2pdf call in R looks as

```
exams2pdf(c("lm.Rmd", "switzerland.Rmd"), n = 1, name = c("MAT210-exam", "MAT210-solution"),
      encoding = "UTF-8", dir = "output", edir = "../MAT210exercises",
      template = c("../templates/exam.tex", "../templates/solution.tex"))
```

So, I hope someone can guide a solution route to enable different labels for cloze items and choice alternatives in this setting. 
I am running R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05). Windows 7, MikTex 2.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the cloze formatting can be controlled "a little bit" by the `cloze.collapse` control argument. And I think you are looking for the `"enumerate"` option:

```
exams2pdf(c("lm.Rmd", "switzerland.Rmd"), template = "exam.tex",
  control = list(cloze.collapse = "enumerate"))
```

This yields the following format in the questionnaire on the title page:

[image: cloze questionnaire]

And the following format in the exercise itself:

[image: cloze exercise]

Note that if the only target is PDF output, it might be easier to split up the combined cloze question into separate exercises. You can still share parameters/data across the exercises if you specify a dedicated environment `envir=` in which the exercises are processed (rather than using a fresh environment for every question). The drawback is that such sequencing of exercises is only available when producing standalone PDF files but cannot be used in learning management systems like Moodle because these all exercises separately. For further discussion of these issues, see the R/exams forum on R-Forge:

https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33878&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337
https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33912&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for clarifying. I think the cause of difficulties here is that the (a), (b).. in question 1 and 2 above are generated from the same latex environment `answerlist`, while probably there should be different environments since (a), (b), .. mean different things in q1 and q2. I managed to change the labels by editing the definition of `answerlist` in `exam.tex` by writing `...\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\roman{enumii})}...`  (note ii rather than i, is there an error in the demo `exam.tex` file?) This however changed all of the (a), (b)'s so basically we have the same problem.

Comment: Whether a/b/... means something different depends on the exercise. For example, imagine a cloze exercise with two num subitems: (a) Compute the mean of x. (b) Compute the variance of x. And then you might have an mchoice question with: (a) The mean of x is 1.23. (b) The variance of x is 2.34. In both cases (a) and (b) are really sub-tasks to the exercise. Hence the same environment (exmchoicelist) is used for both on the front page, it's details are defined in `exam.tex`.

Comment: Ok, I see your point there. I think it would be great in a future version to have a way to allow the same labelling for schoice/mchoice-questions regardless of whether they appear in a cloze problem or as an individual question, (e.g. in your example above, to have labels (i), (ii), (iii),... both for question 1a and 2.)  Also, it appears to me that in `exam.tex` it should be `\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}` (i.e. defining labels at level ii, rather than i). At level i, changes seem to have no effect.

Comment: OK, I'll think about it. I'm a bit reluctant because this will blow-up both the `exam.tex` template (because we need different environments for all the different levels) and the R code (that creates the content). Also, the questionnaire on the front page and the exercise itself have to be in sync. I'm not sure that this is worth all the effort. But maybe copying some environments by default would be possible.

Comment: A follow-up question: In the first R-forge link above, you suggest setting `envir=.GlobalEnv` to allow several .Rmd files to share data. Where exactly should this code go in the .Rmd files?  (I struggled to find exact info about this).

Comment: In `exams2pdf(..., envir = .GlobalEnv)`.